# WebM and Opus in Safari

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, webm, opus

Using patent-free audio and video codecs on the web has always been problematic due to poor support in Safari.  According to the [Safari 15 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-15-release-notes), though, this might be starting to change.  WebM video is apparently now supported in MSE on iPadOS 15, and the Opus audio codec is supported in WebM containers.

According to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/), though, ([WebM](https://caniuse.com/webm), [Opus](https://caniuse.com/opus)) the situation didn't change with i(Pad)OS 15.  On mobile devices, WebM is only supported for WebRTC, and Opus only works if you use a CAF container—which no other browser supports.

My experiments suggest that, unfortunately, [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/) is correct.  I was wondering, though, if anyone can clear up the mystery.  Are the release notes just wrong, as seems to be the case?  Am I misunderstanding the release notes somehow?  Is there some trick that allows you to use these codecs after all?

Comment: Some WebKit bug reports that might be relevant:  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183852  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176650  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176651  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238546  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=226922  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=227111

Comment: Some Test pages: 
[MSE browser tests](https://w3c-test.org/media-source/mediasource-is-type-supported.html) Parent directory has more, 
[MSE tests for audio in different containers](https://chrisguttandin.github.io/mse-tests/) ([Source](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/mse-tests)), 
[Different audio formats](http://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/) Has a .caf testfile

Comment: Thanks, that seems to confirm that Can I Use is correct.  I'm still curious why the release notes seem to say something different.  Hopefully this will all be sorted out in a future Safari release, though, and these formats will be fully supported.

Comment: If you want to play Ogg Opus, https://github.com/Web-Media-Foundation/infrastructure/tree/master/packages/ogg-polyfill can help repackage it into caf right in the browser. Even with CAF, the Apple Safari media stack still only supports Opus hard CBR.